# Wordpress not sending email via sendmail

Tags: wordpress, sendmail

I have moved our wordpress installation from Amazon Linux to Azure (Centos 7).  I have almost everything fine except emails are not being sent from within Wordpress.

I have configured sendmail to send via Amazon SES.

I can successfully send and receive email via sendmail
I can successfully send and receive email via a simple php script

Nothing seems to be working from wordpress.  I am not sure where to start!

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do is to check your spam folder in case the from address domain is different from the aws ses configured domain.

I had a similar problem on my ec2 instance.  I reviewed /var/log/maillog and noticed wordpress was not using the correct from address domain.  And so after integrating amazon ses and sendmail, I also had to change my ec2 hostname.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/sendmail.html

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/set-hostname.html

note that I had to use this line in my /etc/hosts file which was slightly different from the recommendation:

```
127.0.0.1 webserver webserver.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
```